# Hide copy/share/selectAll menu on react native webview IOS/Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-webview

I need to hide the default tooltip menu with copy/share/selectAll options in react-native-webview when text is selected.

[Here the tooltip menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzFI0.png)

Anyone have any idea how to do both this on IOS and ANDROID ?

It will help a lot, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution for Android, and consists in importing `android.view.ActionMode` in  `MainActivity.java` and write this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
...
    public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) { // <= Add this
       mode.getMenu().clear();                        // <= Add this
    }                                                // <= Add this
}
```